# Evaluation of an Error function

Tags: warning-messages

How to evaluate df function in the following code sample?

```
    f[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[x^4-4x^2 y^2]
    df[x_,y_,dx_,dy_]:=Sqrt[(D[f[x,y],x]dx)^2+(D[f[x,y],y] dy)^2]
    df[1,2,0.2,0.3]
```

General::ivar: 1 is not a valid variable. >>
General::ivar: 2 is not a valid variable. >>

Comment: `:=` says to evaluate the right hand side later when the function is called. Next `df[1,2,0.2,0.3]` sets x equal to 1 and y equal to 2. Next evaluate the right hand side doing `D[f[1,2],1]` and you don't know how to differentiate with respect to 1. Same for 2. If you change the `:=` to `=` in your definition of the `df` function and you clear all definitions or restart Mathematica then the right hand side is evaluated before `df[1,2..2,.3]` and the error message goes away. But you must be very careful with this to be certain that the answer is correct.

Comment: It works for this sample, but it does not twork for  more complicated code which contains many functions.

Comment: Please read [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) on how to differentiate `:=` and `=`. It will help you in other contexts too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) instead of [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) in your definitions:

```
df[x_,y_,dx_,dy_] = Sqrt[(Derivative[1,0][f][x,y] dx)^2+(Derivative[0,1][f][x,y] dy)^2];
```

Then:

```
df[1, 2, .2, .3]
```

> ```
> 0. + 0.95219 I
> ```

Comment: I suppose that      df[x_,y_,dx_,dy_]=Sqrt[(D[f[x,y],x]dx)^2+(D[f[x,y],y] dy)^2]   would work

Comment: Yes, the same @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: many thanks  for you @Carl Woll